# Change the aws cloudfront distribution with Lambda Function urls timeout error duration

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I have a cdk stack that's creating a couple lambdas that take in query params and call api's to send data back to the client through a cloudfront distribution through the new cloudfront function urls. This is done through lambdas itself (not a cloudfront function or a lambda edge), and I've noticed through xray that there's a timeout at three seconds by default. I don't know where this is configured but I was wondering if there's a way to increase the duration to something else because I'm pulling images from another api.

All of the errors when I query the api and it takes 3 seconds error out and fail, but the api call comes back as successful.
[image: the timeout errors I'm finding in xray]

Here's the cloudfront distribution, (also I've found that function urls only allow get requests, but it made life a bit easier than having to spin up a whole api to handle these calls)
[image: The cdk code for the distribution]

And if you're curious on how to create function urls for cloudfront distributions on lambda, here is my code:
[image: code to create a function url to connect to cloudfront]

Does anyone know how to configure the function invocation time limit, I'm kinda stumped on this one

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using CDK to configure your Lambda function then the attribute is ['timeout'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Function.html), and it takes a [Duration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Duration.html).

Comment: Oh I hate everything, we have our timeout commented out in the function base params and I didn't think the default would be 3 seconds, also thanks man